# man pages no longer rendering - lots of "permission denied" errors related to pager / vimpager

Tags: permissions, vim, man, pager

For reasons I can't determine, within the last two days the "man" command stopped working on my linux server (Ubuntu 18.04).  When attempting to run `man <anything>` I end up at a blank instance of vi (presumably because it's using vimpager somewhere in the background)... once I quit out of the vim instance I see the following errors on the console:

```
lwobker@lwobker-vms:~$ man ls
cat: /tmp/vimpager_4620/cols: Permission denied
cat: /tmp/vimpager_4620/lines: Permission denied
head: cannot open '/tmp/vimpager_4620/stdin' for reading: Permission denied
sed: can't read /tmp/vimpager_4620/stdin: Permission denied
mv: cannot move '/tmp/vimpager_4620/stdin.work' to '/tmp/vimpager_4620/stdin': Permission denied
cat: /tmp/vimpager_4620/stdin: Permission denied
/usr/bin/pager: 242: /usr/bin/pager: cannot open /tmp/vimpager_4620/stdin: Permission denied
/usr/bin/pager: 239: [: Illegal number:
```

This happens regardless of whether I'm running at a "regular" user, or if I do `sudo man <anything>` or if I do `sudo bash` and run it that way.

Clearly there's a permissions issue somewhere but I'll be damned if I can figure out where.  All the /tmp directories mentioned in the error messages are present and have read permissions set, so I can't quite figure out why all these commands are complaining.

```
lwobker@lwobker-vms:/tmp$ ll vimpager_4234/
total 60
drwx------  2 lwobker lwobker  4096 Nov  8 10:47 ./
drwxrwxrwt 24 root    root    40960 Nov  8 10:56 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 lwobker lwobker    11 Nov  8 10:47 1.vim
-rw-r--r--  1 lwobker lwobker  9664 Nov  8 10:47 stdin
-rw-r--r--  1 lwobker lwobker     0 Nov  8 10:47 stdin.work
```

Comment: Are you able to create or modify files in that folder directly, with eg. `touch /tmp/vimpager_1234/testfile` ?

Comment: Yep... touch, tee, cat, echo - everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that somehow the [apparmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) profiles for the `/usr/bin/man` executable were either corrupted or had be overwritten with the profiles from a different release, or something along those lines...  so the `permission denied` warnings were coming from apparmor and not from the filesystem permission checks.

Checking the syslog showed tons of messages like:

`audit: type=1400 audit(1541703091.843:4554): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="/usr/bin/man" pid=8777 comm="ps" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="/usr/bin/man"`

The solution was a nifty tool that I wasn't aware of called [aa-logprof](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/aa-logprof.8.html), which basically parses the errors from apparmor in your syslog and (interactively) asks if you want to adjust the apparmor profiles to fix the permissions.

Comment: Oh, and if there's ONE TOOL that I never want to be unable to use again... it's "man"  ;-)